# Align elements side by side - Bootstrap 4 col-sm-6 not applying

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In the following code I wish to display to containers side by side in mobile like so:

[image]

However the output I am receiving is both containers stacked on top of each other:

[image]

Despite having col-sm-6 as the div class that wraps each container. Below is my code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <div class="text-center mx-auto our-scope-card mb-5">
        <div class="col mt-5 mb-3">
          <h1>CSS Align</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row pt-4 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col col-lg-8 col-10">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5 pt-5">
                <div class="mb-5 mt-3">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="Dev" />
                </div>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">Application development</p>
                <p>For businesses of all sizes and industries, we can custom design an application to fit your needs.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5 pt-5">
                <div class="mb-5">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="Mobile Apps" />
                </div>
                <p class="font-weight-bold">
                  Mobile applications
                </p>
                <p>Whether iOS or Android, we focus on including features that will bring you ROI and differentiate your platform.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any advice on how to achieve my objective?

Comment: i think something wrong while declaring col span -- <div class="col col-lg-8 col-10"> and use xs -- col-xs-6 to use in mobile extra small screen sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need col-xs-6 class for mobiles screen sizes.

Extra small devices
Phones (<768px)

Comment: Appreciate the insight but applying col-xs-6 does not solve my problem

Comment: Working fine see: http://jsbin.com/kadahelowo/edit?html,output I think one of your other classes must be overriding it.

Comment: Appreciate the insight, you are right. Something higher up the chain is overriding the css